# Storybook for React project with error in Anycable lib

Tags: reactjs, storybook, anycable

When running Storybook in my React project, the following log appears:

```
ERROR in ./node_modules/nanoevents/index.js 10:23
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (10:23)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
|   },
|   on(event, cb) {
>     this.events[event]?.push(cb) || (this.events[event] = [cb])
|     return () => {
|       this.events[event] = this.events[event]?.filter(i => cb !== i)
 @ ./node_modules/@anycable/core/channel/index.js 2:0-45 14:19-35
 @ ./node_modules/@anycable/core/index.js
 @ ./node_modules/@anycable/web/index.js
 @ ./app/frontend/src/javascript/lib/websocket.js
```

I tried updating Anycable libraries from v0.6.0 to v0.8.0, but without success.